# Devise::SessionsController#create setting session doesn't work in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, warden

I'm trying to do integration test for our login process we have overwrite session create process like this:

```
module UsersDashboard
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    protect_from_forgery :except => [:create, :mfa_callback, :authenticate]

    def test
       session[:test] = 'doodoo'
       self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
       render text: 'hi'
    end

    # Used for User Dashboard login
    def create
       current_user = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
       resource = current_user
       current_user.update_attribute(:mfa_authenticated, false)
       # some code here      
       session[:channel] = 'some value'
       p "session channel in create: #{session[:channel]}, #{session.class}"
       redirect_url = 'some value here'
       redirect_to redirect_url
    end 
end
```

and here is my test code:

```
require 'test_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

class DashboardOkTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "Dashboard sign in and visiting various pages inside dashboard " do

    post_via_redirect '/users_dashboard/sessions/mani'
    p session[:test]
    mani = users(:mani)
    post_via_redirect '/users/sign_in', 'user[email]' => mani.email, 'user[password]' => '123456'
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal '/mfa/index', path
    assert_select '#choose-mfa-method', 'Choose Your Acceptto Multi-Factor Auth Method:'
    login_as mani, scope: :user
    p "session: #{session[:channel]}, #{session.inspect}"
    assert request.query_parameters.has_key?(:channel)
    tfa = Tfa.find_by_channel(request.query_parameters[:channel])
    assert tfa
    tfa.update_attribute(:status, 'approved')
    get "/users_dashboard/sessions/authenticate?channel=#{tfa.channel}"
  end
end
```

as you can see in the output:

```
"doodoo"
"session channel in create: 123, ActionDispatch::Request::Session"
"session: , #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7fabecaa9458 not yet loaded>"
"session channel is nil"
```

session[:channel] doesn't work and session is not loaded yet! interesting point is I have created a test method in Session Controller as you can see and if we set session[:test] before calling self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options) session works and it prints 'doodoo' but it's not the case for create method if we set session[:channel] before self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options) it still doesn't work.

It looks like devise has some kind of wrapper that nullifies session after create call. and all this just happens in test while session and everything else works in development server in web.

Any idea how to set a session for test inside create method?